# Deal with Many Choice and Matching Questions in Testing Schema

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Struggling to find a way to allow many choice questions and matching questions in my testing schema. I'm guessing I should have a column in the `QUESTIONS_LINK` table denoting the amount of correct answers for that question. For matching, I just have no clue how to logically relate the somewhat "unrelated" options with the answers for each so that it can be grabbed to be displayed on the web page.  Note: strong/weak relationship lines may not be accurate.  [image: Testing Schema]

Comment: Your ERD already indicates a 1:M between Questions:Answers. So just navigate Question_Link join Questions join Answers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Perhaps an example of what you want to show would help.